# Accessing row of SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im struggling with a bit of my code for my database, I have managed to access the id number of the item i click however i cannot access any more of the data? How can i do this?

For example now i have my id number i want to display all of that data on that row in a seperate window but i cant seem to pull the data with the cursor

```
String itemselect = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
Toast.makeText(Developer.this, itemselect, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
final Cursor cursor = mydb.getAllRows(itemselect);
startManagingCursor(cursor);

String[] fromfieldnames = new String[]{
            DatabaseHelper.COL_1, DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3, 
            DatabaseHelper.COL_4, DatabaseHelper.COL_5, DatabaseHelper.COL_6 };
int[] toviewids = new int[]{R.id.textone, R.id.texttwo, R.id.textthree, R.id.textfour, R.id.textfive, R.id.textsix};
final SimpleCursorAdapter mycursoradapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listtext, cursor, fromfieldnames, toviewids);
listView.setAdapter(mycursoradapter);

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Long string = mycursoradapter.getItemId(position);
        Toast.makeText(Developer.this, string.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

There are no errors in this code I just need to try and add this extra functionality

Thanks in advance M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored in your `Cursor` at the row position `position` in `onItemLongClick`. Use the `moveToPosition()` method on `cursor`, and retrieve the values:

```
String one, two, three;

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        one = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_1));
        two = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_2));
        // Etc...
    }
};
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I need thank you very much

Comment: @Marca Glad to hear it, please mark my answer as accepted to show anyone else that comes across this post that this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

use the cursor in the following way:

```
public Cursor getRowByID(int ID) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = {"id, col_1, col_2, col_3"}; 
    String sqlTables = "your_table";
    String filter = "id= "+ID;

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, filter,null, null,
        null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;

        }
```

Comment: This will be good for future uses thank you very much the answer below is what I need right now but I will use this for future implementation thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor Retrive_SubCategory1(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select "
                + "column_Name1 , "+"column_name2 " + " from "
                +"table_name " + " where "
                + "column_name " + "='" + id+ "'",
                null);
        return cursor;
    }
```